# Convert string to json in Athena

Tags: sql, json, regex, amazon-athena

I have a problem when converting column string to json.

Currently, I don't have any problems with some data as it is currently converting string value to json. The problem occurs when the string value has apostrophe. For me to be able to convert my string value I would replace ' to " but 1 column inside the json sometimes has apostrophe as it is a name.

```
     CAST(json_extract(replace(replace(column, '"', '"'), '''', '"'),'Name"s','Names'), '$.items') as array<json>) as column_list,
```

What I did now is I did many replace to remove those names with "/' but when I checked the numbers of names with apostrophe, it is so many to do my current solution. Any recommendation on this one?

```
 {
    'name': 'Sam',
    'age': 45,
    'cars': [
      'car1': {
        'name': "Hondas Lire'q Car"
      },
      'car2': {
        'name': "Toyota's Car"
      },
      'car3': {
        'name': "Happys' Car"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show the faulty string?

Comment: @GuruStron updated. so there are many words that has apostrophe

Comment: That is not a valid json.

Comment: it is not as this is a string converted to json @GuruStron

Comment: Take any online json validator and check. Possibly you have meant `'cars':'{....}'`?